# Excel Drop down Box

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I was wondering, in the scenario where your wrapped text goes below the bottom margin of a cell, is it possible to have a drop down arrow that shows the full content of the cell?

I would like to know this as I have cells that require a lot of text but I don't want to have the cells in the same row adjusted in anyway. I am working in Excel 2010 if this provides any help.

Okay to adhere to the comments, I have tried adding a list box and linked it to a cell but I cant seem to get a drop down arrow to click that will show the full contents

instead it will only let me scroll through the text by pressing the down arrow I can only read a line at a time.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Did I try what?

Comment: Did you try what you are asking about? Did you try to see if the drop down box will show the full content of the cell? The basic assumption here on Superuser is you've attempted something and run into an problem. [Edit] your question with what you've tried and where you had a problem so we can help you.

Comment: okay im assuming the drop down box does exist in Excel I didn't know it existed my problem is now that I don't know how to create one

Comment: Research is your friend. There are many features available in Excel; list boxes, combo boxes, etc. There are also loads of tutorials on the internet how to use them. Superuser is not the place to learn how to use them; rather the place to get help when you run into a problem using them. Give it a try and update you question with what you need help with. Trial and error is a great teacher.

Comment: Ah well don't I feel an Idiot... I'm an application specialist and I failed to realise that the Developer Options are available in Excel as well as word forgive me haha